# Regex to match less than 500 feet with decimal places in a string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to use regular expressions to determine if a string contains a value of less than 500 feet. Importantly, there are some key constraints and assumptions to the matching:

- Can assume commas have been stripped. Decimals are guaranteed to be `.` and not `,`
- Cannot assume the numeric value is preceded by a space.
- Can assume "feet" will be written as "ft" or "feet"
- Can assume lowercase
- Decimals can be any length
- There may be any number of spaces between the number and word "feet" or "ft"

My attempts thus far:

**Attempt 1**

```
\b[1-4]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,}}){0,1} {0,}(ft|feet)\b
```

This was good, but failed to account for decimals and matches values like 1000.5 ft (matching "5 ft")

**Attempt 2**

My next attempt was to include a negative lookbehind to make sure the match wasn't preceded by a `.` or any number.

```
(?<!(\.|[0-9]))([1-4]{0,1}[0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]{1,}}){0,1} {0,}(ft|feet))\b
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't match any decimals now (e.g., 5.5 ft should match but doesn't). I suspect I'm misunderstanding how negative lookbehind works.

I would appreciate any help understanding where I'm going wrong!

**Test Cases:**

- "1 ft tall" - match
- "1ft tall" - match
- "1.1ft tall" - match
- "He is 6 feet tall" - match
- "499.555 feet tall" - match
- "He is 2 m tall" - no match
- "500 feet tall" - no match
- "The building is 1000.405 ft tall" - no match

Comment: Any particular reason why you are using regexes for this? They are definitely the wrong tool for the job, just let them do the basic screening (`\b([0-9]+([.][0-9]*)?) *f(oo|ee)?t\b`) and then convert the captured numbers to `float`, checking if they are less than 500.

Comment: Try `(?<!\d\.)(?<!\d)(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\d|[1-4]\d\d)(?:\.\d+)?\s*f(?:ee)?t\b`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/l88DfS/2).

Comment: @MatteoItalia The dataset is quite large so I was hoping to be able to use a regex rather than parsing the values and then doing an additional operation to check if there is a match. Not sure if that's a good reason or not!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Beautiful, this seems to work perfectly. I will implement and do some sampling to make sure. Do you want to add as an answer rather than just a comment?

Comment: @MatteoItalia my understanding is the complexity and computation required for your proposed solution would be too much in my use case. The dataset is huge and doing one vectorized operation is preferred. Additionally, each string can have multiple numbers (not explained in my problem description), so the computation could be compounded by having to check an array of values per row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
r"(?<!\d\.)(?<!\d)(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\d|[1-4]\d\d)(?:\.\d+)?\s*f(?:ee)?t\b"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l88DfS/2/)

**Details**

- `(?<!\d\.)(?<!\d)` - two negative lookbehinds that make sure there is no digit + dot or just a digit immediately before the current location
- `(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\d|[1-4]\d\d)` - a number

  - `[1-9]` - from `1` to `9`
  - `[1-9]\d` - from `10` to `99`
  - `[1-4]\d\d` - `100` to `499`
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching an optional sequence of a dot and then 1+ digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `f(?:ee)?t` - `ft` or `feet` (but not `fet`)
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Comment: Thanks! As I mentioned above this seems to work perfectly, but I am doing some sampling in my dataset and, assuming that goes well, I'll accept this answer.